# Links without a space between a URL and tag are not rendered as a link in the chat transcript

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, chat-transcript

If you post a chat message like `[tag:foo]http://example.com/` *(note the lack of a space in between)*, it will be converted to:

[image]

Now when you view the same message in the chat transcript it looks like this:

[image]

It's failing to convert to a link. However, if you *did* put a space it between, it works for both. There shouldn't be a difference in how this markdown is processed in the chatroom and the transcript.

Also, yes I know the lack of space is stupid on the part of the poster, but the rendering should be consistent. I expect when a link properly renders in chatroom it would do so in the transcript.

Comment: Shouldn't the url have parentheses around it?

Comment: @MrLister: In chat URLs are automatically converted to links. So no, you do not need parentheses around them.